# Optimizing objective function in SciPy optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

```py
res_M = minimize(L_M, x0=x_M, args=(data, w_vector),
                 method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=[(0.001, 1), (0.001, 1), (0.001, 1)])

def L_M(x, data, w_vector):    
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        sum += w_vector[i]*(data[i][0]*np.log(x[0])+data[i][1]*np.log(x[1])+data[i][2]*np.log(x[2]))
    return -1*sum
```

As part of an Expectation-Maximization(EM) algorithm I am calling SciPy's `optimize.minimize` function in the M-step. x_M are three values between 0 and 1, initially all 0.5. The w_vectors are calculated in the E-Step, and consist of a NumPy 1D array of the lengths of the data set with floats in the range 0 and 1. Each line in the data set is three integer feature values between 0 and 3, for example [1 0 2].

The for loop in the objective function is slowing things down. I want to optimize it using vectorized calculations instead. I have tried the following, but it changes the result:

```py
def L_M(x, data, w_vector):
        length = len(data)        
        a_i = data[np.arange(length)][0].sum()
        f_i = data[np.arange(length)][1].sum()
        l_i = data[np.arange(length)][2].sum()
        sum = (w_vector[np.arange(length)].sum())*(a_i*np.log(x[0])+f_i *np.log(x[1])+l_i*np.log(x[2]))
        return -1*sum
```

The minimize function is getting called many times and I hope to test it on some very large data sets so any ideas on how to rewrite it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert all your arrays into NumPy arrays and then this can be achieved as follows:

```python
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0]])
w_vector = np.array([0, 1]

def L_M(x : np.ndarray, data : np.ndarray, w_vector : np.ndarray):    
    result = np.sum(w_vector * np.sum(data*np.log(x), axis = 1))
    return -result
```

This part of the code (`(data[i][0]*np.log(x[0])+data[i][1]*np.log(x[1])+data[i][2]*np.log(x[2]))`), where you multiply each element of `data` at ith position with log of each element of `x` and take the sum of all three, is replaced by `np.sum(data*np.log(x), axis = 1)` where element-wise multiplication is achieved (as these are `np.array`) and the sum is taken row-wise and the sum of each row is returned inside a 1D-array.

Afterward, this array is multiplied by `w_vector` (as these both have the same length and are `np.array`, element-wise multiplication is possible).

Finally, the sum of the resulting array is taken and saved into `result`. For optimization, pass `x_M` also as a NumPy array:

```python
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x_M = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

res_M = minimize(L_M, x0=x_M, args=(data, w_vector),
                 method='L-BFG-B', bounds=[(0.001, 1), (0.001, 1), (0.001, 1)])
```

P.S.: Avoid using variable names like `sum` as it is already a Python function and not a good practice IMHO.

Comment: Why did you use `-1*result` and not just `-result`?

Comment: I actually used the OP's style. I changed it now.